# Is it justifiable to implement Observer Pattern on Factory?

Tags: php, design-patterns, observer-pattern, factory-pattern, object-oriented-analysis

I have created a Factory by the name duckFactory which creates different Ducks from some Duck classes, now I want every time a duck is created the duckStore class must be notified. For this purpose, I created a DuckFactoryObserver interface which I implemented on the duckFactory class.

This is the Observer interface I created.

```
namespace App\interfaces\Observers;

interface DuckFactoryObserver {
    public function add( Duck $duck );

    public function notify();
}
```

This is where I Implemented the Observer pattern.

```
namespace App\Factories;
use App\Characters\MallardDuck;
use App\Characters\RubberDuck;
use App\Characters\DecoyDuck;
use App\interfaces\Observers\DuckFactoryObserver;

class DuckFactory implements DuckFactoryObserver {

    private $ducks = [];

    public function duckCreator( string $color, string $duckType ) {

        switch ( $duckType ) {
            case 'mallard':
            return new MallardDuck( $color, $duckType );
            break;
            case 'rubber':
            return new RubberDuck( $color, $duckType );
            break;
            case 'decoy':
            return new DecoyDuck( $color, $duckType );
            break;
            default:
            return 'No Duck of Such Type';
            break;
        }
    }

    public function add( Duck $duck ) {
        $this->ducks[] = $duck;
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach ( $this->ducks as $duck ) {
            echo $duck->display();
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt is, is it a wise choice to implement one pattern on the other?

Comment: I see the word "Observer", but I don't see anything here that looks like the observer pattern.  Either way, it doesn't make any sense for a factory to observe itself.

Comment: thank you sir for your valuable response... but could you please elaborate it a little more @MattTimmermans